# Unable to programatically change navigationController.navigationBar Bar Tint colour using Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigationbar, swift5

In my **Main.storyboard** I have a *NavigationBar* *TintColor* set to **default**.

In my swift file I have below function, where I'm trying to update look and feel of few elements such as search bar colour and navigation bar background colour. Change of colour for search bar is working but background colour for nav bar is not.

Background colour for the navigation bar meant to be based on the colour selected on previous View Controller hence I'm tapping into (`selectedCategory?.color`).

Using `print(navBarColour)` I confirmed that correct/expected colour is getting picked up, however somehow my navigation bar still shows default colour.

Can anyone help please?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if let colourHex = selectedCategory?.colour {
            title = selectedCategory!.name
            guard  let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else {fatalError("Navigation does not exists.")}

            if let navBarColour = UIColor(hexString: colourHex) {

                navBar.barTintColor = navBarColour
                navBar.tintColor = ContrastColorOf(backgroundColor: navBarColour, returnFlat: true)
                navBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: ContrastColorOf(backgroundColor: navBarColour, returnFlat: true)]
                searchBar.barTintColor = navBarColour

                print(navBarColour)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have just made color-related changes in your code snippets and it worked perfectly.  Can you please share your issue in brief

Comment: The issue I have is that `navBar.barTintColor = navBarColour` doesn't  have any affect on the color. Even if I hardcode colour to .red still no changes are showing. I wonder is this got something to do with the fact I'm using *ChameleonFramework* in this ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to change the background color of the navigation bar as follows:

```
bar.backgroundColor = .red
```

It's worked for me. Hence, you can use your color value, make sure you are passing correct UIColor value in this property.
I hope it helps to resolve your concern.

Comment: he issue I have is that navBar.barTintColor = navBarColour doesn't have any affect on the color. Even if I hardcode colour to .red still no changes are showing. I wonder is this got something to do with the fact I'm using ChameleonFramework in this ViewController?